# limiting the no. of characters entered in textbox html helper element in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using a order form as follows,                                                          <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToCart", "../ShoppingCart", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleUpdate", OnBegin = "ajaxValidate" }, new { @class = "AddToCartForm" }))
  { %>

<%=Html.Label("Quantity")%>
      <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Count)%>

<% } %> 
Now if i entered a large no of t-shirts like 999999999999999999999999999999999999 the Form was unresponsive.So i should limit the no of characters entered in the textbox.So please tell me how to set this limitation so as to not having integer overflow.

Thanks in advance,

And i also restrict they cannot order more than 2*10^31-1  or 32-bit signed integers can hold.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in MVC 2 is to take advantage of the inbuilt validation by using data annotations.

For the Quantity field you should use the Range annotation.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) is a great post to walk you through it, and if you follow it to the end he covers using jquery to do the client side validation too.

Answer (score 0):

Use MaxLength="Number of characters you wish user should enter" in your code ..

as

```
         <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Count, new {MaxLength="10"})%>
```